# storing data for circle drawn on mapview in kml

Tags: ios, kml, geometry

Does anyone have the idea for storing the circle coordinates which is overlayed on mapview in kml file

any help would be appreciable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Use this iOS framework for parsing/generating KML files: [Simple-KML](https://github.com/mapbox/Simple-KML)

2.Calculate circle coordinates

```
    NSMutableArray * circleCoordinates = [NSMutableArray array];
    CGPoint centerCoordinate = CGPointMake(37.422f, -122.082f);
    int steps = 1000; // bigger steps, smoother circle you get
    float radius = 10.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
        KMLCoordinate *coordinate = [KMLCoordinate new];
        coordinate.latitude = centerCoordinate.x + radius * cos(2 * M_PI * i / steps);
        coordinate.longitude = centerCoordinate.y + radius * sin(2 * M_PI * i / steps);
        [circleCoordinates addObject:coordinate];
    }
```

3.Generate KML file with the framework by the circleCoordinates you get.

Btw: you can use this [web KML Circle Generator](http://thesamestory.com/kmlcircle/) to learn what a circle KML file looks like